# include view template into other template

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

How to pass parameters to the  included view template ?

**Controller**

```
public function action_index3()
    {

   $view = View::factory('view1');
   $view ->set('name','Tokyo');
    $view ->set('age','1980');
    $this->response->body($view);
    }
```

view1.php

```
<?php
include 'view2.php';
?>
<?php echo $name; ?><?php echo $age; ?>
```

How to pass variable to the template view2.php? Only GET include 'view2.php?name='+val?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function action_index3()
{

    $view = View::factory('view1');
    $view ->set('name','Tokyo');
    $view ->set('age','1980');

    $subview = View::factory('view2');
    $subview->set('meow', 'woof');

    $view ->set('subview', $subview);
    $this->response->body($view);
}
```

Then just echo $subview in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `View::set_global($key, $value)`